# Best way to handle Angular templates of different parts of the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I saw different ways of using nested templates inside of directives but none of them work great. At least I didn't manage to solve various issues.

So what is an idea is - I need to create a re-usable directive which consists of different logical parts (like header, footer, menu, action bar, content, selector etc). What I need to is to have an ability to specify the whole template and the templates for different parts just inside of the HTML layout like this:

```
<videoBoard>
    <header-template>{{heading}}</header-template>
    <menu-template><a ng-click="showVideo()"/></menu-template>
    <content>
         <a ng-href="{{item.link}}" ng-repeat="items">{{item.caption}}</a>
    </content>
<videoBoard>
```

Based on this definition there will be created target HTML layout as if I specified it directly in the directive. The same I need to be able to specify via code using HTML elements passed by scope variables.

Something like that. If we don't specify some of the templates here we use the default one (defined separately or defined inside of the marked part of the overall template). All the stuff like scope, tracking the changes should work.

So how to do this best?

Comment: Are you looking for ngTransclude?  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngTransclude

Comment: I know about this but by default it allows to use this only once for the directive. I saw in angular bootstrap the approach to use custom transclude directives but the solutions works a bit tricky with passing transclude function from parent controller to the child and then using it to handle transclusion.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Do you mean that there is a template for videoBoard that includes those tags and that you want that template to be used except those tags will be replaced by the specified tags if they are present?

Comment: Exactly what you described. Also need a way to pass them dynamically by loading the templates externally from files or from the database or from external CMS.

Comment: I have to say, for something like the snippet you have above transcluding those elements and passing their transclude functions to a controller in `videoBoard` sounds like the optimal solution...it's used a few different places in angular. For loading external templates, would just using a few ng-include's in a master template suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too broad for a single SO question.  If you want to ask a separate question about the dynamic templates, here is one way to replace items...  [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/CN35F/)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
    <h1>Template H1 for {{name}}</h1>
    This should replace everything, but the &lt;h1&gt;
    element can be overridden
</script>    

<div class="boxed">
    <parent>
        <h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>
        This should say only the person's name
    </parent>
</div>

<div class="boxed">
    <parent>
        This should say whatever the default is
    </parent>
</div>
```

[image: templatable templates]

Using `transclude` and `compile` instead of `link` we can use a template and still gain access to the original elements.  The `compile` function returns a function like the normal `link` function returned by directives.  It takes `linker` as an argument which is a function you can call and provide another function with access to the original elements (`clone` here).

```
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    compile: function(element, attrs, linker) {
        // need to return linking function
        var parent = element.parent();
        return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            linker($scope, function(clone) {
                // 'clone' is a copy of the original elements in our 'parent' element
                var existing = $element.find('h1'); // in template
                if (existing.length == 1) {
                    // look for replacement h1 element specified in code
                    for (var i = 0; i < clone.length; i++) {
                        if (clone[i].tagName == "H1") {
                            // replace h1 element in template with specified
                            $element[0].replaceChild(clone[i], existing[0]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

This uses the template and completely replaces whatever is between the `parent` tags, but the original content is accessible using the `clone` argument.  Here I take the `h1` element if present in the original and use it to replace the `h1` element in the template.  The syntax is a little funny, I was hoping I could just do a `clone.find('h1')` but clone appears to be an array of JQLite objects I think and find doesn't work.